# How to encrypt Google Drive on local machine

Tags: hard-drive, security, encryption, google-drive, google-workspace

I'm a Google Apps customer and one of the things I'm using is the Google drive service to sync my files from my work PC to my home. This works fantastic but I have a concern about theft of the machine locally.

Google likes to pride themselves with how secure there cloud based services are using multiple arrays, multiple locations and data encryption. However it's my understanding that all files are stored locally and are not encrypted which to me means that your data can be stolen, read, copied and modified.

I have tried using EFS on the Google drive on my desktop but Windows 7 reports an error. I've looked through all settings of Google drive and can't find an option! this seems a major flaw... unless I'm missing something.

Question

How can I encrypt the files locally when using Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Trust nobody looks like boxcrypter is your best bet .. https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Drive+encrypted+drive

you can do it cheaper with something like Amazon clouddrive  etc